# RAID / drive configuration for an intranet MongoDB server

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, mongodb

I'm trying to get a handle on the best way to configure a Dell PowerEdge R410 for hosting a MongoDB-backed intranet application.

The R410 has 4 drive bays and a PERC 6/i controller.

RAID10 is the recommended RAID level for MongoDB, so my initial thought is to use 4 drives in RAID10 and partition the single virtual disk into DB, OS, etc. partitions.

With only 4 bays, the only other real alternative would be to use 2 disks in RAID1 for the DB, and 2 disks in RAID1 for the OS, etc.

The server will see about 100 concurrent connections, mostly writes at the rate of 50 writes / sec (across all users).

Would a partitioned RAID10 be the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is always RAID 10